# HP ProLiant ML350e Gen8 - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: server, hp, raid, 14.04

I was researching about new Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS and the Proliant ML350e Gen8 with B120i RAID controller. I found that HP certified Ubuntu without RAID engine on 12.04 server version, but now I cannot find any documentation of Award Process of Certification for Ubuntu of this model, does anyone know anything about that? Will that model be fully certified, any one know how to make Ubuntu 14.04 work with RAID driver in HP Proliant ML350e Gen8 with B120i RAID controller?